# You have an error in your SQL syntax : saving strings

Tags: php, mysql, string, escaping

I have an array of strings in my session which I am trying to store to the database. But I am getting an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

My code is as follows:

```
$improve =$_SESSION['post']['improve'];

if(is_array($improve))
    {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO student (improve1) values ('%s')";
    $valuesArr = array();
    $i=0;
    for ($i=1; $i <=$childtoen; $i++) 
        { 
        $improve_list="";
        if ($improve[$i][0]!="")
                {
                    $improve= mysql_real_escape_string( $improve[$i] );
                    $improve_list = implode( ',', $improve); echo $improve_list;  //echo is working Fine
                }

        $improve_list = mysql_real_escape_string( $improve_list );
        $valuesArr[] = "('$improve_list' )";
        }

$sql .= implode(',', $valuesArr);
mysql_query($sql,$connection) or exit(mysql_error()); 
}
```

What could be the reason as I am also escaping the string? I even tried escaping the imptove_list but no help.

Comment: What is the complete error message?

Comment: Just `echo` the result query and see what is wrong. It's obvious!

Comment: do `echo $sql` and show us the result. And why every new user uses `mysql_*` functions? They are **deprecated**, don't use them. Learn mysqli or even better PDO. `mysql_*` is deprecated.

Comment: The Complete Error is 

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('ADHD,ASPERGER' )' at line 1`
@juergend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you get an error as `$sql .= implode(',', $valuesArr);` just append the imploded array to your predefined string and so the SQL-Statement is invalid.

edit: After reading your now posted errors message.

When I understand your script correctly `$valuesArr[] = "('$improve_list' )";` is too much. The final result of this would be `('ADHD,ASPERGER')`. I think this will result in a SQL-statement like `INSERT INTO student (improve1) values ('('ADHD,ASPERGER')')` And then you have the given error as the `'` cuts your SQL.

Easy way if would be to change your base sql to `INSERT INTO student (improve1) values %s` if you make sure the result in `$valuesArr[]` is always like `('ADHD,ASPERGER')`.

But I would suggest you just store the real values (ADHD, ASPERGER, NEXTVALUE, ANOTHERVALUE, ...) in your array and build the sql like this:

```
$sql = sprintf($sql, implode(',', $valuesArr));
```

This would replace the placeholder `%s` with the string from the implode. Then you should be save as you avoid the `('` and `')` for each value

Comment: you mean `$sql .= implode($valuesArr);` ?
if i do this error disappears but the value in databse is `%s`.

Comment: I updated my answer after you posted your error message.